# Authenticate Web Browser with SSL certificate

Tags: php, authentication, browser, ssl

Is it possible to authenticate a web browser using an ssl certificate.

Say i store a private key in my application, is there any way to read a key from a browser and try to authenticate based on that?

Comment: "*Say i store a private key in my application*", it's not clear where you think the private key should go here.

Comment: You can have private key in browser's certificate store or in smart card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can authenticate a browser/user using SSL/TLS client-certificate authentication.

The client certificate must be requested by the server, so you'd need access to the server configuration (not just installing some PHP code on a shared server). This is done at the SSL/TLS layer (in fact, the mechanism is not specific to HTTPS): the server requests the client-certificate during the SSL/TLS handshake (sometimes via a renegotiated handshake). In Apache Httpd, this is typically done via [`SSLVerifyClient`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient) (although you'll need to specify other options too).

The server will then verify the certificate against the CAs you've configured it with (possibly your own, and possibly independent of the CAs used for the server certificate itself). (Alternatively, you could disable certificate verification at the server level in some cases, and have the PHP application do it, but this is a bit more advanced and you'd need to know what you're doing.)

You can access the client certificate from your application and obtains its Subject DN (or alternative names), to identify the client.

It's not clear whether you're after identifying a *browser* or a *user*. In the end, everything goes through the browser anyway, but client certificates tend to be allocated to users. Users would have to install that certificate into their browser.

---

**EDIT:** For further details, it would help if you could clarify your question and what you intend to do with this.

> Is it possible to authenticate a web browser using an ssl certificate.
>
> Say i store a private key in my application, is there any way to read
>   a key from a browser and try to authenticate based on that?

Firstly, strictly speaking, there's no such thing as an "SSL certificate", since multiple types of certificates can be used for SSL/TLS, and some of these same certificates can also be used for other purposes than SSL/TLS. Typically, "SSL certificate" means "X.509 certificate in the context of SSL/TLS".

Therefore, authenticating a web browser using an SSL certificate implies doing it at the SSL/TLS layer. (There have been attempts to implement message-level security using X.509 certificates at the HTTP layer, but they're not widely supported by browsers.)

Secondly, the private key is held by the remote party that you authenticate. The local party that authenticates the remote party doesn't see any private key. If you (as a server) want to authenticate a web browser, it's the browser that needs to have the private key, not your (presumably PHP) application. In this context, it's not quite clear why your (PHP?) application would have/need a private key if it's the browser that you want to authenticate.

What your verifying application may need (if it's not done by the server itself) is a CA certificate to be able to verify the client certificate it is presented with (or at least some form of trust anchors with which to verify the client certificate). There's no private key required here, just public keys and certificates, unless you want your application to be a CA too.

Indeed, you could have your application be a mini CA. It could make the browser generate a key-pair and send a certificate request to the server (there are mechanisms to have a web page make the browser do all that). Then the server would generate the certificate and make the browser import it back against its private key. Subsequently, the browser could use this certificate for authentication with that server (or other servers that would recognise these certificates).

Comment: +1 Exactly as you said.I did several SSL enabled deployments this way.

Answer (score -2):

No, you cannot do that.

There is some development going on, and a few day ago W3C has made a proposal for a encryption standard.

You can however put a key in a cookie and use that to identify. This is the default PHP session id behavior.

Comment: Would that be secure? having a key in a cookie?

Comment: "*No, you cannot do that.*": short assertive statement, but without any reference/justification. Any reference to back this up? You can authenticate a client using a certificate.

Comment: @Stephen: nope, a key in a cookie is not very secure. However, most of the 'remember me' from shops are stored in a cookie. It all boils down to a combination of a smart key and good authentication on the server. You could encrypt the IP of the client in the key and check that.

Comment: @JvdBerg You can not store SSL private key in session cookie, because this is available after HTTPS parameters are negotiated.See Bruno's answer

Comment: If you're not familiar with SSL client-cert authentication, here are a few links: [1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19212-01/817-7612/ax_ssl.html), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_Public-Key_Cryptography#Certificate-Based_Authentication) and [3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/) (for example). Admittedly, it's not necessarily great from a UI point of view, but it's widely supported by most browsers and servers. (You can of course convey this form of authentication to PHP.)

Comment: @Bruno: I read the question as: can the browser use a SSL certificate to identify itself with the server. HTTPS and SSL certs are a server side business.

Comment: Well, not with client certificates, they're client side too, not just server side. There's a reason why you get a *Personal* tab in the Certificates options in IE's Internet Options, or a *Your Certificates* tab in FF's *View Certificates*. You clearly haven't even looked at those links here or in my answer, or even googled "SSL client (or mutual) certificate authentication"...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a problem, I'm merely pointing out why your answer is incorrect (and I admit I downvoted it for this reason). (I was surprised to see mine downvoted, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: Sor you answer on this question: Say i store a private key in my application, is there any way to read a key from a browser and try to authenticate based on that? your answer would be yes?

Comment: As I said in a comment to the question (hard to say without further input from the asker), it's not clear what he has in mind with "*storing a key in my application*" (that doesn't quite make sense). For the rest, yes, a browser using a client-certificate will indeed send a public key (within its certificate) to the server for authenticating, and the PHP application can authenticate the user/browser based on that. (The SSL/TLS client-cert mechanism also ensures that the user/browser has the corresponding private key for the client cert, otherwise there would be no authentication, of course.)

Comment: For me it was very clear, exactly as asked And the answer must be no. It bid childish of you to down vote my answer.

Comment: The question isn't clear on that point actually. SSL certificates can only be used at the SSL layer (since "SSL certificates" really means "X.509 certificates used for SSL"): if you removed "SSL" and did it all at the HTTP layer, "SSL cert" would be non-sense anyway, and the question clearly is about "*using an ssl certificate*". Hence, yes, it *is* possible to authenticate a browser with an SSL certificate, it's widely supported (but maybe not widely used). You can even make the PHP application make the browser generate its key-pair (to request a cert).

Comment: Please read the question again: he is not asking about a client side certificate! For the second time: "is there any way to read a key from a browser and try to authenticate based on that?" The answer on that is "No, you cannot do that." Very annoying that you down voted my correct answer!

Comment: (I guess I'm also annoyed someone downvoted mine ;-) ). Anyway, the client-cert key when you get the authenticated cert with the request on the server comes from the browser. The principle of public key crypto means that the private key never leaves the browser (and will never be sent), but that's how SSL (client) certs work: the browser uses its private key and sends its cert/pubkey. All of this involves reading a key from a browser (whichever way is implied: the browser reads its private key and the server reads the public key coming from the browser) and authenticating based on that.

Comment: I rest my case, perhaps you have some knowledge about SSL, but you are not gifted to read a simple english sentence.

Comment: No need for this sort of remarks. I'm just pointing out that there are inconsistencies in the question (which is fair enough if the asker isn't quite sure how it all works). The fact remains that it is possible to authenticate a web browser using an SSL/X.509 certificate.